# Why do i still see MVC 3.0 referenced in object browser after upgrading to MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-assembly

I upgraded an asp.net-mvc website to asp.net-mvc 4 and one thing i noticed is that in the object browser I still see MVC 3.0 referenced (as well as 4.0) but i went through all fo my projects and all of the references are to the 4.0 version. (see screenshot below)

[image]

I restarted / rebooted, etc thinking it might be some caching issue but it still is showing up.

Any suggestions on why that would still show up there or is there anyway to find out what is referencing it?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if your reference a different assembly which in turn references System.Web.Mvc.dll v3.0.

Comment: is there anyway to do a reverse lookup to see what other assembly would have this reference?  Do i need a binding redirect in this case?

Comment: Most (all?) decompiles should show referenced versions, and yes.

Comment: Resharper will show you code dependent on an assembly when you right click on the reference.